# looping & echoing divs results outside of its parent div except the 1st child

Tags: php, html, echo

as the title says I loop several divs which is supposed to be inside their parent but only the first child is inside

there are 2 php file, one is the template the other is for generating content

here are php code :

The Template

```
<div class="badan">
  <?php include "isi.php" ?>
</div>
```

The Content (isi.php)

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM produk WHERE id_kategori2='4' ORDER BY id_produk DESC LIMIT 4"); 
echo "<div class='produk-box'>"; 

while ($r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

  include "diskon_stok.php";

  echo "<div class='produk'>
        <div class='produk-title'><a href='produk-$r[id_produk]-$r[produk_seo].html'>$r[nama_produk]</a></div>
        <br />
        <a href='produk-$r[id_produk]-$r[produk_seo].html'><img class='produkimg' src='../foto_produk/small_$r[gambar]' title='$r[nama_produk]'></a>
        $divharga
    </div>";
    }
  echo"</div>";
```

now the parent is `div class=badan` while the childs are `div class=produk-box` and the level 2 child is `div class=produk`
my intention is to make all of `produk` echoed inside `produk-box` while `produk-box` is echoed inside `badan`

but what's really happening is the first `produk` is echoed **INSIDE** `produk-box`, the second `produk` is echoed **OUTSIDE** of its parent div, and the rest of `produk` is echoed **OUTSIDE** of `badan`

here is the screenshot of google chrome inspect element :

[image]

Comment: You have an extra **</div>** - somewhere.

Comment: I checked with html language on notepad++ all the divs are correctly closed. if I'm wrong can you tell me where is the extra?

Edit : sorry. I forgot I included diskon_stok.php, that's where the extra **</div>** is.  phew it took me hours to remember that file

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<div class='produk-box>'";
```

should be

```
echo '<div class="produk-box">';
```

Comment: thanks. I misytped there, because I didn't copy pasted it